# Oracle SQL - IN Clause display all record given in IN condition even when data not present in table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `customer` as described below.

`customer_id number
customer_name varchar(30)
city varchar(20)`

columns. When the below query run in Oracle db

`SELECT customer_id, city FROM customer WHERE city IN ('abc', 'def', 'ghi')`

I'm getting the output as shown below. Table doesn't have record for `ghi`

`customer_id, city
1, abc
2, def`

I'm trying to form the output something as below.

`customer_id, city
1, abc
2, def
null, ghi`

Though no record for `ghi` in table, want to display it in SELECT query output with rest of the column value as null.

Much appreciate help in writing sql for this scenario.

Comment: you can. But, why do you want that ? Also, which database are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Oracle 10

Comment: You didn't asnwered why do you need that ?

Comment: IN doesnt generate a list.. `customer IN ('abc', 'def', 'ghi')` works like `customer = 'abc' OR customer = 'def' OR customer = 'ghi'`

Comment: That is **not** your query, if you are getting **any** input from it. Why? Because the query you wrote is syntactically incorrect. The `IN` condition needs to be in a `WHERE` clause, but there is no `WHERE` clause in your query.

Comment: @Ravi, it is the requirement, need to generate a report, typically, will execute this query with multiple data in IN clause, some would have records, few don't. Manually have to compare the query output with, IN clause dataset. Just want to know it is possible in Oracle? if so, please write an query.

Comment: How will you arrive on values for `IN` clause. `('abc', 'def', 'ghi')`. I mean is the value for `IN` clause is fixed. If not then how are you picking it up.

Comment: How many values do you usually have in your IN clause?

Comment: @isaace, 100+ values will be there in IN clause

Answer (score 5):

You need a derived table containing all possibilities. Either you have one, like a city table and then you can do:

```
SELECT t.customer_id,s.city
FROM city_table s
LEFT JOIN customer t
 ON(s.id = t.city) 
WHERE s.city IN ('abc', 'def', 'ghi')
```

Or generate the values your self:

```
SELECT t.customer_id,s.city
FROM (SELECT 'abc' as id FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 'def' FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'ghi' FROM DUAL) s
LEFT JOIN customer t
 ON(s.id = t.city) 
WHERE s.id IN('abc', 'def', 'ghi')
```

Comment: But, there is no record

Comment: @Ravi and? The city table will populate it, and you commented to fast :S there's already an edit.

Comment: @sagi who says it will always be 'ghi?'

Comment: No one, that's why I gave two options. If options one is not possible, then there's no other way to do it then option two. @isaace

Comment: you can't use SELECT 'def' in Oracle you need to use the dummy table dual.. so SELECT 'def' FROM DUAL

Comment: Thought it's SQL Server , my bad . @RaymondNijland

Comment: @sagi but, that's not making sense. There is no data and he wants that to be display ?

Comment: Who says there is no data?.. It sounds logically correct that there is a city table stored(as long as the design is correct) @Ravi

Comment: @sagi OP himself mentioned *Though no record for ghi*. But, I'm not going to argue further. It's upto OP. ;)

Comment: @Ravi Mmm, I understand your point, not sure if that's the case but it's possible.. lets wait for the OP

Comment: @sagi, Thanks for the quick turnaround, but in my case, IN clause would have nearly 100+ strings, forming those with dual table, will be a beating around the bush, is there any simple query for this case.

Comment: Not that I can think of. What you can do, is create a table with all the values need to be checked, and compare against it. @SriramM